# Google Play app not showing in search results when searching from Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I have made a simple game using the Unity game engine. I have tested the apk from my Android device and uploaded it to the Google Play store. The app is published and showing in the search results from my PC and device browser, but I can't find it from in the Google Play app on my Android device - not even from the device that I have used for testing during development. Some devices' browsers say that the app is incompatible with the device.
I want to understand and resolve the problem.

I have used Unity 4.3 and the game is a 2D game. Here is my `androidmanifest.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"package="com.Codebrazier.Wizball" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
</activity>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
</activity>

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You published your app 2 days ago, maybe you just have to wait a few days more? Your manifest seems ok.

Comment: I am new at android development and don't know much about the google play publication systems.So it may be a silly question...As it is showing on search result from the web browser,doesn't it mean that the app is fully published?If I wait some more days is there any chance to change anything that I will find it from mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case the reason was using Texture Compression that was not compatible with some devices. I solved it by switching to the ETC1 texture format. More info can be found in the Unity Documentation - Inside the Android Build Process (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html).